# duplicate formula with return info

Tags: excel, duplicates, countif, maxifs

I have a table with two columns A and B. On column A I have some ID s and on the B column and have dates. On A the Id s are not unique. I need you help to build a formula that will search on A for duplicates ID s and if there are, to show on C column on the ID with the recent date ,,True,, and on the other duplicates ,,False,,. If are uniques ID s, on C must show ,, True,, .

Something like on the attached picture table...

[image]

I appreciate if you will help me with a formula instead of an VBA code

[sample picture table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBBnR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=[@date]=MAXIFS([date], [id], [@id])
```

[image]

If you get a `#NAME!` error then search this site for [[excel][maxifs]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel%20maxifs?mode=all) to find a compatible solution.